# wondering why empty inner iterator causes not serializable exception with mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: apache-spark, iterator, partition, serializable

I've been experimenting with Spark's mapPartitionsWithIndex and I ran into problems when 
trying to return an Iterator of a tuple that itself contained an empty iterator.

I tried several different ways of constructing the inner iterator [ via Iterator(), and List(...).iterator ], and 
all roads let to my getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) had a not serializable result: scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1, value: empty iterator)
        - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _2, type: class java.lang.Object)
        - object (class scala.Tuple2, (1,empty iterator))
        - element of array (index: 0)
        - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
```

My  code example is given below.  Note that as given it runs OK (an empty iterator is returned as the 
mapPartitionsWithIndex value.)  But when you run with  the now commented-out version of 
the mapPartitionsWithIndex invocations you will get the error above.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to this can be made to work, I'd be much obliged.

```
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object ANonWorkingExample extends App {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("continuous").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val parallel: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 9)
  val parts: Array[Partition] = parallel.partitions

  val partRDD: RDD[(Int, Iterator[Int])] =
    parallel.coalesce(3).
      mapPartitionsWithIndex {
        (partitionIndex: Int, inputiterator: Iterator[Int]) =>
          val mappedInput: Iterator[Int] = inputiterator.map(_ + 1)
          // Iterator((partitionIndex, mappedInput)) // FAILS
          Iterator()   // no exception.. but not really what i want.

      }

  val data = partRDD.collect
  println("data:" + data.toList);
}
```

Comment: Not how I understood to use mapPartitions. Never seen the "  ..  val parts: Array[Partition] = parallel.partitions ... used this way, but learnsome.  More so this way http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/11/mappartition-example.html or calling a function . But may be I am learning something new ...

Comment: I like SBT BTW.

Comment: Curious as to your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the dumb thing I was doing was trying to return an unserializable data structure: an Iterator, as clearly indicated by the stack trace I got.

And the solution is to not use an iterator. Rather, use a collection like a Seq, or List.  The sample program below illustrates the correct way to do what I was trying to do.

```
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object AWorkingExample extends App {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("batman").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val parallel: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 9)
  val parts: Array[Partition] = parallel.partitions

  val partRDD: RDD[(Int, List[Int])] =
    parallel.coalesce(3).
      mapPartitionsWithIndex {
        (partitionIndex: Int, inputiterator: Iterator[Int]) =>
          val mappedInput: Iterator[Int] = inputiterator.map(_ + 1)
          Iterator((partitionIndex, mappedInput.toList)) // Note the .toList() call -- that makes it work
      }

  val data = partRDD.collect
  println("data:" + data.toList);
}
```

By the way, what I was trying to do originally was to see concretely which chunks of data from my parallelized-to-RDD structure were assigned to which partition.  Here is the output you get if you run the program:

data:List((0,List(2, 3)), (1,List(4, 5, 6)), (2,List(7, 8, 9, 10)))

Interesting that the data distribution could have been more optimally balanced, but wasn't.  That's not the point of the question, but I thought it was interesting.

Comment: Your comments actually are a little overstated.

Comment: Looking at this again I realized why the distribution is not balanced... The elements are slotted into each partition based on some hash of the element MOD num-partitions... so the reason for the imbalance is that the data is skewed visa-vi the partitioning function applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve and I am a sort of novice compared to some of the expert folks here.

I present something that may give you an idea of how to do things I think correctly and make some comments:

1. You seem to get the partitions explicitly and call mapPartitions - a 1st for me.
2. RDD inside mapPartitions and the various SPARK SCALA thing will not fly; it is about iterables and I think you need to drop to SCALA only level.
3. The serializeable error come from doing List[Int].

Here is an example showing index partition along with those corresponding index values.

```
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Minutes, Seconds, StreamingContext}
// from your stuff, left in

val parallel: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 4)
val mapped =   parallel.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
                       (index, iterator) => {
                          println("Called in Partition -> " + index)
                          val myList = iterator.toList                          
                          myList.map(x => (index, x)).groupBy( _._1 ).mapValues( _.map( _._2 ) ).toList.iterator
                       }
                 }  
mapped.collect()
```

This returns the following that resembles a little of what I think you seemed to want:

```
res38: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((0,List(1, 2)), (1,List(3, 4)), (2,List(5, 6)), (3,List(7, 8, 9)))
```

Final note: the documentation and such is not so easy to follow, you don't get it all from word count example!

So, hope this helps.

I think it might get you on the right path to where you want to go, I could not quite see it, but may be you can now see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Thank you for your response..  What I was trying to achieve was muddied by additional code that I didn't need to illustrate the question... I will fix that.

Comment: It is not all that intuitive and not for everyone. There are so many data engineers who have no notion of this. You might want to upvote as I think I might have helped you on your way.